# Overloading cout with template class

Tags: c++

I'm rebuilding my class as a template and I'm having trouble with overloading cout (working without the template). gcc throws this error when I try to compile:

```
error: ‘LinkedList’ is not a type
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, LinkedList&);
```

The code for the LinkedList.h class is:

```
template <typename value_type>

class LinkedList
{
public:
LinkedList();

~LinkedList();

void addToHead(const typename node<value_type>::value_type& entry);
void addToTail(const typename node<value_type>::value_type& entry);
void set_current(node<value_type>* entry);
void remove(string);
void remove_from_head();
void remove_from_tail();
void list_clear();

int list_length();
int count(string name);
double calcAverage();
bool search(string);
node<value_type> * get_head();
node<value_type> * get_tail();
node<value_type> * get_current();

LinkedList& operator+=(LinkedList&);

private:
node<value_type>* head;
node<value_type>* tail;
node<value_type>* current;
};
template <typename value_type>
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, LinkedList&);
```

I assume this has something to do with templates and that this part of the code is outside the scope of the class but different combinations of typedef and  just seemed to cause more errors.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I think you just didn't look carefully enough at examples and started guessing instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed `LinkedList` is not a type there, it is a `template`.

You can create a type out of the template by instantiating it, substituting it's template parameters with types.

```
template <typename value_type>
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const LinkedList<value_type>&);
```

Edit: As suggested by @Scheff the linked listed should also be `const`, because the `operator<<` should never change it.

Comment: Yepp. And for the upvote, make it `template <typename value_type>
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const LinkedList<value_type>&);` as `<<` should never change the data which is put out.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `LinkedList` is not a type indeed. `LinkedList<int>` or `LinkedList<std::string>` is a type. While `LinkedList<value_type>` is a type template used to build actual types.

What you need to do is to specify the template parameter as follows:

```
template <typename value_type>
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, LinkedList<value_type>&);
```